# Boolean Value Confusion when it is local, open and recursive in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion, boolean

I am a beginner and really confused with this code as what happens to boolean value, "done". I have spent two hours understanding this code and I am very frustrated.

```
public boolean traverse(int row, int column){

boolean done = false; 

if(row == grid.length-1 && column == grid[0].length-1)
     done = true;
else{
     done = traverse(row + 1. column); //down
     if(!done) done = traverse (row, column+1)//right
     }
if (done) grid[row][column] = PATH;
}
return done;
}
```

First, "done" is declared FALSE. Then it moves to an if and else statement and becomes local to it.Now, outside the IF and ELSE statement, when it says if(done) do something, it is when done is FALSE or TRUE? Also while in the ELSE statement does (!done) mean that it is FALSE as it is declared TRUE in IF ELSE statement?

In simple words, when you use an IF, IF and ELSE statement with a boolean in it, does it mean it has to be TRUE?

For instance:

```
boolean love = false;
if(love) do this;
```

Now, does it mean "do this" when love is false?

Comment: this code won't run as it is because there is a { missing somewhere...

Comment: @OblTobl don't worry, I will figure it out with my teacher tomorrow.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: check this example for booleans http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/udacity-asked-question-done-is-boolean.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `!` operator negotiates the boolean value. That means a statement becomes `true` if the boolean variable is `false`. So, for your example this won't be executed:

```
boolean love = false;
if(love) do this; //not executed
```

But with a `!` it would be executed:

```
boolean love = false;
if(!love) do this; //executed
```

In the other case this wouldn't be executed:

```
boolean love = true;
if(!love) do this; //not executed
```

**EDIT:**
For further explanations on if-Statements maybe you will have a look on the official docs by oracle:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

**EDIT 2:**
Maybe if you write your code this way it is more understandable for you:

```
public boolean traverse(int row, int column){

   boolean done = false; 

   if(row == grid.length-1 && column == grid[0].length-1) {
      done = true;
   }else{
      done = traverse(row + 1. column); //down
      if(!done) {
         done = traverse (row, column+1)//right
      }
   }
   if (done) {
      grid[row][column] = PATH;
   }
   return done;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, so for done, when it says (done) it is outside the block or if else statement, so does it mean when done is false according to you.

Comment: i really don't understand what you want to tell me with your comment, i'm sorry.

Comment: if (done) {
      grid[row][column] = PATH;
)

The statement will execute only when done is true then, am I right?

Comment: But no worries, I will resolve the entire code with the teacher tomorrow.

Comment: In the else block, everything done there is false, is this right as well?